# What happen if someone transformed via Polymorph Any Object uses an Alter Self special ability?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, polymorph

If I use a scroll of *Polymorph Any Object* to permanently turn into a dragon, can I use an *Alter Self* spell-like ability to turn into an human for a few hours? And when I stop using it, do i return to my dragon form?

Comment: Just casting *polymorph any object* is not enough when you are a human to turn permanently into a dragon, but I guess you can do that with a few intermediate steps.

Answer (score 8):

Both spells are from the [Transformation (Polymorph)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Transmutation) school, which says:

> **You can only be affected by one polymorph spell at a time.** If a new polymorph spell is cast on you (or you activate a polymorph effect, such as wild shape), you can decide whether or not to allow it to affect you, taking the place of the old spell.

If you cast *Alter Self*, the effects from *Polymorph Any Object* are lost and you cannot turn back into your previous polymorphed form.

Also, [Polymorph Any Object](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/polymorph-any-object/) does not turn your character into a dragon, it puts a magical effect on your character that changes his form to that of a dragon. What means that if you are a Kitsune, your *creature type* remains *Humanoid*, it doesn't change to *Dragon* nor you actually become a dragon creature.

So, even though the spell duration says *Permanent*, it is still an **on-going spell effect**, that can be dispelled at any time, such as when you decide to polymorph into a new form.

Spells with *Instataneous* duration (such as [Cure spells](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/cure-light-wounds/)) do cause instant and permanent changes that cannot be reverted or dispelled, which is not the case here.

Comment: Are there any *Instataneous* (and thus non-dispellablle permanent) polymorph spells?

Comment: Why wouldn't *polymorph any object* turn the character into a dragon? It explicitely "functions as *greater polymorph*" which "functions as *polymorph*" which "transforms a willing creature into [...]".

Comment: @AnneAunyme he has the form of a dragon, he didn't become a dragon.

Comment: @Cyberson as far as i know, no.

Comment: If you are transformed to X, you became X. That's what the verb "to transform" means. Moreover for the specific case of dragons there is a reference from *greater polymorph* to *form of the dragon* which explicitly tells "you become a [...] dragon". (When the more advanced versions of the spell states "you to assume the form of a [...] dragon" as if it was the same thing.

Comment: That's fine if you think that way, but an Elf which casts Alter Self to transform into an Orc does not become an Orc, but an Elf with a transmutation effect that changes his form to that of an Orc.

Comment: A ranger with favourite enemy (Orcs) does not gain his bonus against him. But a ranger with favourite enemy (Elves) would still gain all his bonuses even if this elf assumed the form of a dragon.

Comment: Can you back that up?

Comment: Nor the rules for polymorph nor the spell's says you change your creature type. If your creature type doesn't change, you didnt become a creature of that type.

Comment: There are very few spells that actually say that it changes your creature type (or subtype), Reincarnation being one.

Comment: [Fluid form](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedPlayersGuide/spells/fluidForm.html#fluid-form) is one example of such a spell and even that only treats you as if you had the water subtype, it doesn't give it to you or turn you into a being with it.